# UWP socket client exception when try to connect : ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

Tags: sockets, uwp, task, facebook-c#-sdk

I would like to create an UWP client socket. I use a StreamSocket but I get an error when trying to connect it. 
In other words when the code reaches `await ConnectSocket(IP, PORT)`, the following exception is thrown:
I don't understand the following exception :

> A task was canceled. 
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>       at BluetoothLEExplorer.Models.SocketWriter.d__7.MoveNext()
>
> ```
> System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
> ```

Here is my code of my socket class :

```
public class SocketWriter
{
    private StreamSocket socket = null;
    public StreamSocket Socket
    {
        get
        {
            return this.socket;
        }
    }

    private String errorMessage;

    public async Task<Boolean> ConnectSocket(string host, string port)
    {
        try
        {
            socket = new StreamSocket();
            socket.Control.KeepAlive = true;
            HostName hostName = new HostName(host);
            await socket.ConnectAsync(hostName, port);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public async Task<Boolean> Send(string message)
    {
        try
        {
            Stream streamOut = socket.OutputStream.AsStreamForWrite();
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(streamOut);
            await writer.WriteLineAsync(message);
            await writer.FlushAsync();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            StopSocket();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Boolean StopSocket()
    {
        try
        {
            socket.Dispose();
            socket = null;
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Why I have this exception and how can correct it ?

Comment: Have you ruled out the possibility of a time-out?

Comment: No, how I ruled out ?

Comment: I mean: have you tested if the "task is canceled" isn't due to a timeout on the connection attempt. You can test it by measuring the time needed to throw the exception. If it takes a while; the connection probably times out, most likely due to a firewall suppressing all response on that port. If the exception is thrown immediate, then we need to see if we can get more info.

Comment: The exception is thrown immediate. all IP (good and bad) cause the same error.

Comment: Hmm... is there an inner exception?

Comment: No, I have no InnerException ... But In Visual Studio, in release mode, the application freeze and crash when i try to connect on any IP without displaying exception

Comment: Just to make sure: firewall is disabled on target host (or at least all incomming connections on the port are accepted)?

Comment: No firewall is disable.

Comment: Do you test your socket on the same device and use the local host loopback? What are your server code? Please check the document [Sockets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets) to learn more details.

Comment: My server is a Java server on a Debian virtual machine. I can launch a connection request when I try with Google chrome for simple test and It works very well. Now in my app, I have the following error : `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8007274C): A connection attemps has failed because the connected part has not answer after a certain amount of time or the connection has failed because host has not respond`

Comment: See my answer on your another thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51985939/uwp-client-socket-block-when-try-to-connect-on-java-server-release-mode